# How to use Spannable in SurfaceView

Tags: java, android, textview, surfaceview, spannable

We can use Spannable to adjust text color, font and background in TextView and EditView. But now I want to use it in SurfaceView, there are some images and texts in my SurfaceView. I want to implements the following picture's function, I have finished the begin/end cursor handle and know the selected text's position(rect), but I have no ideas for how to mark it. so can I use Spannable on SurfaceView? any ideas for this?

[image]

Comment: `android.text.Layout#draw()`

Comment: what is this? can you give me some documents or examples? @pskink

Comment: what is what? this is a method that draws a `Layout` on the `Canvas`, see `android.text.Layout` documentation

Comment: maybe it is a way to do this, but I know it needs the canvas of surfaceView,

Comment: you want to draw it on this surfaceview, right? so you need its canvas

Comment: Actually I have tried to use PopupWindow, but PopupWindow is expensive, so I want to find some ideas to do this. I used follow code to get Canvas, But after this, I find PdfSurfaceView become a black View. I can't see everything except for this rect. 

SurfaceHolder surfaceHolder = surfaceView. getHolder() ; 
Canvas   canvas  = surfaceHolder.lockCanvas() ;  
// draw       
surfaceHolder.unlockCanvasAndPost(canvas) ;

Comment: so did you try Layout#draw()?

Comment: I have tried it, but when I get the canvas SurfaceView will be black

Comment: post your code then (using `Layout#draw`)